# WebBroswer Navigate is trying to download a json file

Tags: ajax, json, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 to create a Visual Basic application. I am using a web browser named `mail`

When I use the Navigate function, it will go to the `php` page, but then it won't show the results like it does a with normal browser. Instead, it tries to download a JSON file.

This is the command I am using in `mail`:

```
mail.Navigate("http://api.guerrillamail.com/ajax.php?f=get_email_address&ip=" & ReturnIP() & "&agent=VBProject")
```

If you go to this URL in the Visual Basic project, it will try to download `ajax.json`.  However, if you go to it in a normal browser, the JSON file is displayed on the page, and it looks like:

```
{"email_addr":"hoppoxyn@guerrillamailblock.com","email_timestamp":1400779801,"alias":"dcoipje+wwy9y0","sid_token":"4fqkl2q9mlp4uvgki5fkckk4q3"}
```

Is there a way to do this in Visual Basic? I added a reference to JSON.NET to my project.

Comment: ReturnIP() is just a function that calls for the IP address not the LAN IP

Answer (score 0):

Visual Basic runs the test environment in IE7. To accomplish this you need to make changes to your registry.

Open Notepad and paste the following:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00;
; Tell IE 7,8,9,10,11 to open JSON documents in the browser on Windows XP and later.
; 25336920-03F9-11cf-8FD0-00AA00686F13 is the CLSID for the "Browse in place" .
;
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type\application/json]
"CLSID"="{25336920-03F9-11cf-8FD0-00AA00686F13}"
"Encoding"=hex:08,00,00,00
```

Save the file as  `IE-Json.reg`

*Remember to always back up your registry before making changes*

Run `IE-Json.reg`